# Get element from a list relative to another element in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list. I want to get an element by iterating through it. I am getting an element which is 2 indices after the element that I'm looking for. How do I get the element that I want ?

Example code:

```
for x in list:
    if "y" == x:
        ## get my element based on above condition
```

Comment: Please post an example code and what you have tried.

Comment: Just added an example code.

Comment: How your list looks like and what will be your expected output?

Comment: Is `list[list.index("y") + 2]` what you need? Note about handling possible errors/exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember which list index you are up to so you can go forward 2. The simplest way to do this is to use the `enumerate()` function which produces a list of (index, value) pairs.

```
for i, x in enumerate(list):
    if "y" == x:
        print(list[i+2])
```

Note: `list` is a builtin function so it can be confusing to use it as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = ["test", "test1", "test2"]


print(list[0])
print(list[0+2])
```

Result:

```
test
test2
```

More in general, your element:

```
list[x]
```

The element that is 2 indices after that:

```
list[x+2]
```

Edit:

```
list.index("y")
```

gives you the index, then add 2 to this number like described above

Answer (score 1):

### Use the below code with `exception` handling:

```
a = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]
print (a[a.index("bb") + 2])  # find element is "bb" in list "a" and return the +2 index value

# result: dd
```

### Edited code with exception handling and multiple existing values:

```
aa = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "ee", "bb"]

j = []
for i, v in enumerate(aa):
    if v == "aa":
        if aa[i+2:]:
            j.append(aa[i +2 ])

print (j)
```

Comment: If there are multiple "bb" in the list, then how do I get all unique +2 index elements ?

Comment: use enumerate function and list comprehension to get all the occurrences and then get the value of each +2. I will post the code shortly.